# Firebase cloud message with dynamic body content is not changing

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

headers:

> Content-Type:application/json
>
> Authorization:key=your api key

```
{ 
"notification": {
    "title": "Your Title",
    "text": "Your Text",
  },"to" : "daPcA4y33Wg:APA91bFB1m3fj38BjyPUlfk-N4F4oWM4EkQZeyZvjVFJv-18vc4GN2rfIVbBGp59VMDjeO9A3D52itL8gehW20SwL0rcoT066v65g6ciq64d36ys6WTofSXTnc_wD1phfBZbKjR2V7Ns"}
```

The title and text content is not changed. its reflects the service-worker.js content. how to use this content as dynamic content. please help

Comment: What prevents you from using variants instead of invariants?

Comment: Your payload has an invalid structure. Other than that, can you provide more context on what you want to achieve and what you've already done. It's quite unclear what you're asking at the moment.